# Custom IComparer for Int64

Tags: .net, list, binary-search

I have a about 5000 Int64 in a sorted [List](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6sh2ey19(v=vs.110).aspx).

I want to do a [List.BinarySearch](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w4e7fxsh(v=vs.110).aspx) but only based on the 39 bits on the left. 
I am packing information in the bits to the right of the 39. 
Basically the 39 bits to the left is the Key and I am packing a value in the 12 bits to the right.

For a class you just MyClass : [IComparer](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8ehhxeaf(v=vs.110).aspx)

How to add a custom IComparer for Int64?

I know how to use masking to efficiently extract the 39 bits.

I know I could just use a Dictionary but I want to save some space and the way I use it I need the packed data.  I am receiving it has packed data.

I guess I could just write a custom binary search.

I was asked for an example.  For example will use byte which has 8 bits. Each entry is identified by the 4 left bits.  And I am storing some data in the 4 right bits.  Basically the 4 bits on the left is the key and the 4 bits on the right is value.

```
0000 1010
0001 1010
0010 1010
0011 1010
0100 1011
0101 1011
0110 1011 
0111 1011
```

I want to be able to search on 0011 and get the index of 4th row (3). 
When I search I don't know what the 4 bits on the right are. 
Yes the 4 bits on the left are unique. I can just sort on the byte as the bits on the left will determine the proper sort.

If there is a better approach then great.  I have a packed Int64 where the key is the left 39 bit.  I want fast search based on that key.

Simplified code sample

```
public void ListBinaryLeft()
{
    List<byte> fourLeftFourRight = new List<byte>();
    for(int i = 0; i < 16; i+= 2)
    {
        byte newRow = (byte)((i << 4) | 1);
        fourLeftFourRight.Add(newRow);
        Debug.WriteLine("Hexadecimal value of {0} is {1} {2}  i {3}", newRow, String.Format("{0:X}", newRow), Convert.ToString(newRow, 2).PadLeft(8, '0'), i);
    }
    Debug.WriteLine("");
    fourLeftFourRight.Sort(); //actuall not necessary
    for (int i = 0; i < 16; i += 2)
    {
        int findRow = fourLeftFourRight.BinarySearch((byte)(i << 4));
        Debug.WriteLine("key index of {0} is {1} ", i, findRow); //strange getting a negative and off by 1
        findRow = fourLeftFourRight.BinarySearch((byte)((i << 4) | 1));
        Debug.WriteLine("cheat index of {0} is {1} ", i, findRow);  //works but this is not what I need
    }          
    Debug.WriteLine("");
}
```

Comment: It's very unclear what you expect the comparison to do. Could you provide more information? A [mcve] would really help...

Comment: @JonSkeet OK will work on the question.

Comment: Do you need to use `SortedList`? It sounds like you could probably just use a `List<long>` and then sort it with your specific `IComparer<T>` - and that just needs to mask the relevant bits and compare the result.

Comment: @JonSkeet But I don't know how to write that IComparer for Int64.  The syntax eludes me.  And I want to use a BinarySearch for speed.

Comment: Yes, you can use binary search *after you've sorted the `List<T>`*. If you use the non-generic `SortedList` you'd end up with boxing as well. It would really help if you could post a [mcve] which only misses out the custom comparison part.

Comment: @JonSkeet OK I provide an example.  You are going to make me work for this one.

Comment: "You are going to make me work for this one" - I'm trying to get you to ask a good question, that's all. This isn't "punishment" or anything. This site is meant to be a repository for high quality questions, and this isn't one yet.

Comment: @JonSkeet I am not complaining.  I added code sample.  Of up not not being able to search on the key.

Comment: That's still not a [mcve], but it's better than nothing...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/141374/discussion-between-paparazzi-and-jon-skeet).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your comparer just needs to compare by masking and then comparing the results. (Shifting works too - they're basically equivalent here, although masking allows your key to be *any* set of bits in the input, rather than necessarily the most significant bits.) To use your example - but as a minimal complete console app:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

class Test
{
    static void Main()
    {
        List<byte> list = new List<byte>();
        for(int i = 0; i < 16; i+= 2)
        {
            byte newRow = (byte)((i << 4) | 1);
            list.Add(newRow);
        }

        var comparer = new MaskingComparer(0xf0);
        // Only needed if the values aren't added in order to start with
        list.Sort(comparer);

        for (int i = 0; i < 16; i += 2)
        {
            int index = list.BinarySearch((byte)(i << 4), comparer);
            Console.WriteLine($"Key index of {i} is {index}");
            if (index >= 0)
            {
                byte value = (byte) (list[index] & 0xf);
                Console.WriteLine($"Associated value: {value}");
            }
        }          
    }
}

class MaskingComparer : IComparer<byte>
{
    private readonly byte mask;

    public MaskingComparer(byte mask)
    {
        this.mask = mask;
    }

    public int Compare(byte lhs, byte rhs) =>
        (lhs & mask).CompareTo(rhs & mask);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out.  How to do the syntax for the IComparer just spooked me.  Some how thought I had to extend Byte.

```
public void ListBinaryLeft()
{
    List<byte> fourLeftFourRight = new List<byte>();
    ByteLeftFourKey byteLeftFourKey = new ByteLeftFourKey();
    for (int i = 0; i < 16; i+= 2)
    {
        byte newRow = (byte)((i << 4) | 1);
        fourLeftFourRight.Add(newRow);
        Debug.WriteLine("Hexadecimal value of {0} is {1} {2}  i {3}", newRow, String.Format("{0:X}", newRow), Convert.ToString(newRow, 2).PadLeft(8, '0'), i);
    }
    Debug.WriteLine("");
    fourLeftFourRight.Sort(byteLeftFourKey); //actuall not necessary

    for (int i = 0; i < 16; i += 2)
    {
        int findRow = fourLeftFourRight.BinarySearch((byte)(i << 4), byteLeftFourKey);
        Debug.WriteLine("key index of {0} is {1} ", i, findRow); 
        findRow = fourLeftFourRight.BinarySearch((byte)((i << 4) | 1));
        Debug.WriteLine("cheat index of {0} is {1} ", i, findRow);  //works but this is not what I need
    }          
    Debug.WriteLine("");
}
public class ByteLeftFourKey : IComparer<byte>
{
    // Compares by 4 left most bits
    public int Compare(Byte x, Byte y)
    {
        return (x >> 4).CompareTo(y >> 4);
    }
}
```

Comment: I personally wouldn't bother shifting - I'd just use masking. Either would certainly work though.

Comment: @JonSkeet How would I mask?

Comment: Exactly as per my answer. Use the `&` operator. You'll need to know about that in order to extract the value anyway.

Comment: I compare this to Dictionary and Dictionary was about twice as fast.  But even searching on 100,000 item is was just 50 ms compared to 25 ms.

Comment: Well yes, dictionaries are typically O(1) access rather than binary search which is O(log n). But they will take more memory.

Comment: I had it wrong as was not accessing the data from List.  So binary search is a 4x as long as Dictionary.

Comment: @JonSkeet Yes I think I will take the hit here and use BinarySearch as I would like to save memory and that is how the data is formatted already.  I will leave it open for a day before accepting and answer.  Thanks.

Comment: @JonSkeet In using it with 6000 rows the BinarySearch was barely behind Dictionary so I went with BinarySearch.